# Excel | Sum Rows With Different Lengths

Tags: excel, sum, conditional-statements

I will explain my problem by showing my sample data:

```
name    Days    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13
10709219    18  1                                                   
16702083    62  1                       1   1       1   1   1   1   1
16813934    17  1       1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
95800320    13  1           1   1   1       1               1       
194401496   7   1   1   1   1   1   1                               
500050432   6   1                                                   
500757917   21  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
502378479   14  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   
504742011   30  1   1   1   1   1               1   1               
504831056   6   1           1                                       
506359373   24  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

I have this excel structure, 1 and the blank spaces represents user's login in that day to our web site. 
I would like to find the ratio of the user's login behavior.

But the problem is I want to sum up the 1's with respect to the Days value in each row.

For example for the first user, I will sum up until 18, whereas for the second user I have to sum up until 62.

How should I do that in Excel ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is on `A1:P12`, paste this formula to Q2, then drag to copy down.

```
=SUMIF($C$1:$P$1,"<="&$B2,$C2:$P2)
```

Comment: thanks a lot !
I have one more question. I wrote AND("<="&DB769,">="&CY769) in order to sum the range of numbers. But it always gives 0. How should I sum the ranges ??

Comment: You will need [SUMIFS](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/msoffice/use-sumifs-to-sum-by-multiple-conditions-in-excel/6538)